# Connect JavaScript and Ms Sql

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2012

Here is scope of the project I know enough html and CSSs to  build a website. I know enough of MS sql to build stored procedures and complicated quires. I'm trying to bring everything to new next level

The question is very broad but I need some navigation. How do I build web based app to retrieve data from MS Sql with JavaScript? Now I'm studying  JavaScript I only know very basic stuff but I'm ambiguous enough to learn it more as long as I can figure this project. I know that Javascript doesn't have direct way to generate direct connection to SQL server.

What do I use in this case?  What would be the quick tutorial YouTube video or book?  What are the possible ways with node.js,  C#, or any other method that will a concise connection between JavaScript and MS Sql server?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use node js, Node js has a many ORM wrappers like http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/ and  https://www.npmjs.com/package/orm.
This helps to connect to any database like mysql or postgresql or any relational store.